# Pass class as param into function for comparison in swift?

Tags: swift, function, class, parameters, compare

I want to write something like this:

```
func someFunc<T, U>(t1: T.Type, t2: U.Type) {
    let k = someArray.first {$0 is t1}
    ...
}
```

It writes:

`Use of undeclared type 't1'`

Objective-C has `Class` and has class comparison but it seems swift hasn't it properly implemented.

Comment: Objective C's `Class` works in the narrow scope of classes available to the Objective C runtime. Swift's tuples, structs, enums and classes can't play along, for the most part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a generic function you can use the generic type `T` instead of `t1`.

```
let k = someArray.first {$0 is T}
```

Comment: Thanks the hell is `t1` has type `T.Type` but I should use simply `T`